# Sencha Touch: what is the preferred way to persist a store whose model has an Ajax proxy for offline access?

Tags: sencha-touch

The title sums it up. Just looking for the most elegant, preferred way to persist models backed up by an ajax proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.LocalStorageProxy